# the webflux to consume server sent events have no valid response

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, server-sent-events

I want to use webflux to consume some server sent events in Java 11, this is the minimal runnable code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        consumeServerSentEvent();
    }

    public static void consumeServerSentEvent() {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("https://chat.poemhub.top");
        ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
                .uri("/v1/completions?q=hello")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer sk-DRjSqzDl3xHL1234663AfET3BlbkFJfQXGId4540GNmZqr7ss");
                    httpHeaders.set("Content-Type",MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM.toString());
                })
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(type);

        eventStream.subscribe(
                content -> {
                    log.info("Time: {} - event: name[{}], id [{}], content[{}] ",
                        LocalTime.now(), content.event(), content.id(), content.data());
                    },
                error -> {
                    log.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error);
                    },
                () -> {
                    log.info("Completed!!!");
                }
        );
    }
```

when I using curl command to test the sse api, it works like this:

```
➜  ~ curl -N -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-DRjSqzDlwieHL12UvxAfET3BlbkFJfQioueNmZqr7ss" https://chat.poemhub.top/v1/completions\?q\=hello

[{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":"\n","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":"\n","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":"Hello","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" there","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":"!","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" How","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" can","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" I","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" help","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":" you","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"},{"id":"cmpl-6xEWYsb3cce1Xni4Xsqv8OdkU2EpQ","object":"text_completion","created":1679575202,"choices":[{"text":"?","index":0,"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}],"model":"text-davinci-003"}]%
```

but when I run this code using webflux to recived the server side events, no log output. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this problem?

Comment: `subscribe` is not blocking operation and most probably you application exists before receiving data. Try to add Thread.sleep(N).